# why am i getting "undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass" when i'm not calling the strip method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, twilio

I'm building a rudimentary app using the Twilio API, and have reached a block when using figaro to store account_sid and auth_token as environment variables in application.yml.

In my controller I have:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'figaro'
class TwilioController < ApplicationController

def voice   
account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

message = @client.account.sms.messages.create(:body => "Hello",
:to => "+12345678",
:from => "+12345678")
puts message.sid
end
end
```

And in config/application.yml I have:

```
# TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID: 1234567890
# TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN: 1234567890
```

The program works as intended when I replace the env variables with actual values, so the most I'm able to grasp at the moment is that something is preventing those variables from being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move constants to development.rb

and then just:

```
account_sid = TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
```

Comment: The constants are in application.yml (which is also added to .gitignore) for security purposes. Wouldn't moving them to development.rb and doing the same for that file defeat the purpose and cause further problems?

Comment: not sure about that. But if doing that for security reason, stick with yml file as you doing, but refer to http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file and check if the yaml file is loaded.

Comment: the revised one is better http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised

Comment: I'm dense as hell. Just realized I had to uncomment the key-value pairs, and place the value in a string. This railscast really helped though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5 and started getting this error.

For me, it was because a newer HAML version was no longer tolerant of a pre-existing empty javascript block.

```
:javascript
```

I deleted the ':javascript' line and everything was fine afterwards.